# What do "yield type" and "duration" mean in this table of bonds?

Tags: bonds, financial-literacy, terminology

In this [table of bonds](http://www.globeinvestor.com/servlet/Page/document/v5/data/bonds/?order=d&sort=BID_YIELD&page=1), what do the columns "Yield Type" (values e.g. "C", "M") and "Duration" mean?

I thought "Duration" would be the number of years to maturity, but the values seem to be something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/duration.asp) has this definition of duration:

> The duration number is a complicated calculation involving present
>   value, yield, coupon, final maturity and call features. Fortunately
>   for investors, this indicator is a standard data point provided in the
>   presentation of comprehensive bond and bond mutual fund information.
>   The bigger the duration number, the greater the interest-rate risk or
>   reward for bond prices.

As for Yield Type, I suspect C would be Coupon bonds while M would be bonds that the interest would be paid at Maturity.